# Django: Query & render objects from a queryset into a list

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I am making a query on one object which is a `ForeignKey` field on another object, and trying to render the second query as a list. Is there a proper way to access the second query as I'm getting the object to render within the list- but it is inaccessible.

```
mymeals = Meal.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
reservations = []
for meal in mymeals:
    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(meal=meal)
    reservations.append(reservation)
```

This works, but a forloop renders - `[ < Reservation: Reservation object > ]`

```
 {% for reservation in reservations %}
  <p>{{reservation}} {{reservation.user.first_name}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

How can I get the reservation object to render properly so I can display the user first name?

Comment: What does the `Reserveration` model look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mymeals = Meal.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(meal__in=mymeals)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Never knew about __in